# How to read different XML Elements in single class property?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a `xsd.exe` output c# class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class OrdinateZacrep
{

    private decimal xField;

    private decimal yField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal x
    {
        get
        {
            return this.xField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.xField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal y
    {
        get
        {
            return this.yField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.yField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And XML simple:

```
<ordinate>
 <x>587865.52</x>
 <y>1397457.84</y>
</ordinate>
```

But somtimes XML looks like:

```
<ordinate>
 <x>587865.52</x>
 <_y>1397457.84</_y>
</ordinate>
```

How can i read this simples with single class?

Here is xsd slice:

```
<xsd:complexType name="OrdinateOut">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Parcel coordinates</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:decimal">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Ordinate X</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:decimal">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Ordinate Y</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: What produces the `_y` element in the xml file? Can you show us your xsd file?

Comment: @Samuel `_y` not a valid for xsd schema. But here is too much xml documents with `_y` and i can not ignore it.

Comment: Not familiar with the C# code, is this question about changing the C# code that generates an XSD automatically, or about changing the XSD so that both XML documents you show will be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using private variables xField and yField.  So just create a new property that saves to xField and yField like this

```
public decimal _y
{
   get
   {
      return this.yField;
   }
   set
   {
      this.yField = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think its problematic to actually try to modify a (generated) schema file to force it to accept invalid elements according to the schema specification. I rather would recommend to create a translation step  to translate invalid to valid xml files. I would think it would result in cleaner C# code because by this you are not going to deal with incompatible xml files inside the code itself. What's your opinion to this?

Comment: I'm not saying to modify the schema.  Who ever generated the file never did a schema check.  I'm just say the best solution is just to modify the class by adding additional properties.  It is the best chose unless you want to custom parse the entire xml using other Net Library methods which is what you are saying.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: He would need to adjust the schema from which the code is generated anyway to actually introduce the ability to consume either `y` or `_y` otherwise the XML parser won't really be able to read it, or am I wrong? What should the parser do if `_y` is set, but `y` is not? `y` is not nullable therefore it would either `throw` or use `default(decimal)` and the consumer of the xml file wouldn't know which field to use?

Comment: Schema checking is not done automatically when deserializing (even though a schema my be in the xml).  So no change is needed to the schema.  If you go back and automatically create the classes using a tool like xsd.exe then each time you run xsd.exe then you would need to add the new properties.  But hopefully this problem would be fixed when generating new xml files so problem is just a temporary fix until root cause is resolved. I probably wouldn't include the set property so only the reading would be look for the _y

Comment: @jdweng Your solution works fine. It is true that this is temporary solution couse current xsd schema just a project and not officially accepted yet.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to apply a xslt to transform xml files not according to your schema as a pre process step. It should be safe to be applied on xml files which are already correctly formatted.

This xslt for instance renames all `ordinate/_y` elements to `ordinate/y`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ordinate/_y">
        <y><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></y>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can test it on this [page](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) and there are examples on SO on how to use XSLT in C#, just google it :)

Edit: I forgot the brute force way: String replace `<_y>` and `</_y>` in files before parsing them. I do not recommend this but it might be a solution.